# How to give collaborators on Github push access if it still asks for a username and password?

Tags: git, github

I don't understand the reason of collaborators having push access to a repo if you still have to enter a username and password, doesn't that defeat the purpose? or is it just so they can have more access to the repo such as making branches, closing issues, etc... but they use pull requests to make their changes like anybody else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If GitHub asks for a user name and password (it doesn't always, e.g. when using SSH) those are the *collaborator's* credentials, not yours. You never have to, and never should, share your credentials with anybody.

Of course, authenticating your collaborators is important. You wouldn't want me to pretend to be one of them and push arbitrary commits to your project.